# Embedding theorems for Dini continuous functions

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes

Are there embedding theorems for the space of Dini continuous functions on a Euclidean domain, or even just on an interval? Ideally, I am looking for something like the classical Morrey inequalities that describe the embedding of Sobolev spaces into the space of Hölder continuous functions.